# How to prevent blue oxidation / corrosion from growing back?

Tags: pcb, repair, corrosion

I've got a PCB for an old console. It had some blue corrosion which I cleaned off using some diluted vinegar and isopropyl. Its not the typical brown rust when it has been exposed to water or white drying residu.

I've noticed that after a while the oxidation grows back, without the PCB having been used. How can I prevent this from happening?

Do I need to apply some sealer after cleaning?
Did I not clean the PCB properly?

Comment: Vinegar may work as a cleaner BUT is a potential problem in its own right. At a minimum it should be cleaned off completely afterwards. Maybe swabbing with pure IPA would wor. I'd avoid the vinegar if possible. || Polyurethane spray can be used as a conformal coating - although it may be hard to limit its area of application without masking. Avoid getting it on connectors where it MAY wick up between contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Industrially, stuff called "conformal coating" is applied to PCBs for a variety of reasons, but it will keep moisture out and generally massively extend the time over which oxidation residue forms.

For hobbyists, clear nail polish works, though you might want to be careful so as not to allow the acetone in the nail polish to dissolve the silkscreen patterns on the PCB.

If the oxidation is not causing functional problems, you might just let it go.

Comment: Just letting it go is not generally a good idea--it will eventually become a problem as it corrodes away the copper. "blue oxidation" sounds a lot more like something caused by a leaking battery or something than just oxidation from the air, which tends to tarnish copper but not cause a very noticeable color difference unless you put it right next to clean copper.